# GitHub Archived Repositories

Tags: data-mining

I'm trying to build a model that observes patterns of source control usage, from how many files are changed per commit, how many contributors there are, even semantic analysis on the commit messages.

What I'm trying to do is see if I can find a correlation between any of these patterns and the relative "health" of a project.

Since "health" is a fairly subjective term, I'm defining it here to be the amount of activity during a period of time relative to the repository's highest period of activity. Basically, I assume that when there is more activity in the repository by more people, the repository is in a "healthier" state. Very possibly that's a terrible metric, but it's the one I'm using.

My problem is, I want to find some *dead* repositories. I want to find repositories where it was hugely popular, then went to nothing. A great example would be if the Windows Phone source code was all open source.

Does anybody know how I might go about finding these kinds of repositories on GitHub? (Or perhaps do you know of any?)

I see that GitHub has a way to mark a repository as a "Public Archive," but I don't see a way to browse all archived repositories.

I apologize if this is not the correct forum, if it is, please help direct me to the correct place.

Comment: Maybe look at [Github Archive program](https://archiveprogram.github.com/)?

Comment: Definitely this is a good start, particularly using this list: https://archiveprogram.github.com/assets/img/archive-repos.txt, however there does not seem to be a distinction between active projects and relatively inactive ones. I suppose I could inspect a sampling to try and determine that.